# Why can't we filter unanswered questions by tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, unanswered-questions

In the "Questions" tab/button/section/whateveryoucallit, you can filter by tag: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug
But in "Unanswered", you cannot: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/bug (improperly goes to the "My tags" section)
This would be very useful if you are skilled in one area and want to answer questions in that area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You are on the wrong tab. **Switch away from the My Tags tab**, because it will override your selection (My Tags is effectively a list of tags, so it cannot be filtered.)</s>

<s>Remember, SO tabs are all STICKY. If you select a particular tab one, it will stay selected.</s>

the My Tags tab on /unanswered now overrides and shows exactly what tags are in play, also, it uses your "interesting" tags if you've populated them.

Comment: I don't get it. If I show the questions for a tag by clicking on that tag, there is no "unanswered" tab in the second tab row, only in the first row. And when I click at the "unanswered" tab in the first tab row, it shows questions of all tags again. I don't see any stickyness.

The only thing I see is "Unanswered/My Tags", but this does not help much, since in "My Tags" there are many tags I find interesting, but for which I am not necessarily competent enough to answer questions.

Comment: @hstoerr. Took me a while to work it out. Click "Unanswered" tab, then down the right column you'll find a panel titled "Unanswered Tags", click on your tag of expertise and I reckon you've got what you want.

Or http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/<insert tag here>

Comment: Whoops. Sorry I jumped the gun. My instructions are base on what it looks like you should do but it doesn't work.

@Jeff. I think you should give this a high priority. I want to make it a routine to try and answer one question daily but only for vb.net questions.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Really useful, hopefully I can not be useful and start answering some questions.