# "My tags" tab for main question page

Tags: feature-request, tabs, my-tags

Inspired by the new behavior for my tags: (see [meta:1338](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/why-cant-we-filter-unanswered-questions-by-tags))

Can we get a "My tags" tab for the main list of questions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/by-user/6180 could work

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, what is the by-user syntax?   Also, I want a list of questions with my "interesting" tags similar to what happens if I click on unanswered and click on the "my tags" tab.

Comment: Is that by-user thing a mod only tool?

Comment: I'm very surprised this hasn't come up more often