# How can I just view questions that are tagged with my "interesting" tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, filtering

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Filter view to show only interested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested)
>   [Tab for interesting questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions)

Probably a dumb noob question but I can't find the answer anywhere - how do I only view questions that are tagged with one or more of my "interesting" tags? Evidently SO knows which questions these are, as it highlights them, but they are relatively few and far between and I'd like to improve the visual S/N ratio when viewing new questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7510

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of us agree, but it's not the way the owners want the site to run. They want us to typically see all questions, so that an asker stands a better chance of getting their answer.

Comment: ...but you should've noticed that the question had been asked before several times.

Comment: have the owners actually come out and said that? I've not seen a definite "we will not do it" in any of the questions I've seen raised on the topic...

Comment: Umm... I'm sure I've seen it somewhere. Not sure though. Maybe Jeff will jump in and verify it...

Comment: That's unfortunate - my areas of expertise are somewhat "niche", so typically there is only about 1 question in 100 that I might feel qualified to answer - it takes a long time to wade through all the pages of new questions just to see if there's a question or two that I might be able to help with.

Comment: That's what tag searching is for :)

Comment: I feel your pain. I have about 8 tags that I'm interested in, and that's about it. Having the functionality for "Unanswered Questions" doesn't help either, because of the amount of poor advice given that still receives upvotes.

Comment: The asker stand little to no chance of an answer if their question is buried among a thousand others asked that day the and answerer has to wade through all the <strike>crap</strike> irrelevant stuff to find it.