# Why can't we filter tags by "unanswered"?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I follow questions primarily within a specific tag.  As far as I can tell, there is no easy way to get a list of unanswered questions from the tag page.

That would really help to clean up those questions.

Related:

- [why-cant-we-filter-unanswered-questions-by-tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/why-cant-we-filter-unanswered-questions-by-tags)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/jquery

Gets you all unanswered questions in the `jquery` category, for example. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Thanks!  But just so that I'm not missing something: there is no "clickable" way of doing this, right?  Seems like it would be a useful feature to nudge people towards the unanswered questions.

Comment: @Shane: You can click through by clicking the 'Unanswered' tab, then selecting a tag from the right hand side. There is a tab called 'my tags' which brings up your interesting tags as well. These are also clickable.

Comment: Hand to forehead slap.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As @ire_and_curses mentioned, you can use the Unanswered feature for this. But that gets you those questions which SO considers unanswered -- meaning questions which have answers, but none of the answers have upvotes.

If you want the questions which have no answers at all, use search-fu and a bookmark. In the search field, enter:

> [answers:0 [jquery]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+[jquery])

That's all assuming you want the jquery tag, of course. Replace **[jquery]** with whatever tag you want, enclosed in square brackets.

If you want to see questions that have not been marked with accepted answers, put this on your shoe:

> [hasaccepted:0 [jquery]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A0+[jquery])